# Need an Reactjs indeterminate progress bar and need advice on that

Tags: react-redux

I learn React and Redux and in React I start an async fetch in one `Component` and the result from that is showen in another `Component` that uses the Redux `mapStateToProps` for that `Store` state

I come from Java and want to detach this by maybe creating a new React Component that will listen for start/stop command to toggle the indeterminate progress.

I read React docs and code but has not really written any code jet.

Is this a good approach? If so could/should I use the Redux `mapStateToProps` on this `Component` to let it know what state the progress bar should be in?

Is there some other way to do this maybe not using Redux Store since the state of the progress bar is not something that should be in the Redux store!?